# Put solution of the equation next to the equation

Tags: equations

In a `LaTeX` document I have a series of equations written inside different `equation` environments. I would like to replace the equation number with the solution of each equation. How can I do it?

Comment: i cannot see the point of doing it. you can always use math environments like `gather` in which you can display both the equation and its solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution based on the `\tag` macro of the `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\tag" macro
\begin{document}
\[
   x+1=2  \tag{$x=1$} 
\]
\end{document}
```

Use `\tag*` instead of `\tag` if you don't want to surround the solution with parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you want something like this:

```
$$ 
   \matrix {x + 2 = 5 \cr
            y + 3 = 5}       \eqno (x=3,\ y=2) 
$$
```

Comment: Don't use `$$ ... $$` in LaTeX, use `\[ ... \]` instead. See [why-is-preferable-to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) on this site.

Comment: @Bernard - Who says Petr is using LaTeX? :-)

Comment: @Mico The ***OP*** is using LaTeX, where `$$` and `\eqno` should not be used.

Comment: @Mico: ??? You're rather cryptic today…

Comment: @Bernard - There's also plain-TeX... :-)

Comment: @egreg - Whether or not an answer is suitable for a LaTeX user is a separate issue, isn't it? :-)

Comment: @Mico If one asks how to go by train to somewhere, an answer “you can ride by bike” is not acceptable.

Comment: @egreg - For the record, I've *not* expressed a belief that it's helpful to provide a PlainTeX-based answer to a LaTeX-based question. But we're not going to sway P.O.'s opinion, are we?

Comment: @Mico: I didn't even think of this possibility, as the O.P. mentioned equation `environments`!

Comment: My solution is usable in LaTeX too. The main advantage of such code is its independence of used format, so I never give advice to use something different from `$$..$$`. Moreover, my solution is based on basic stones of TeX: TeX primitive `\eqno` in this case. This primitive is very known in plain TeX, so if OP use plain TeX, this question never occurs. Finally, the "LaTeX train" has railway problems very often because of its complexity (we can see it in this forum) and the bike is much more effective in such situations. You can't get to each place using railway.